# Como colorir o cabeçalho CSS?

Tags: html5, css3

Estou tentando colorir um `<header></header>` com CSS porém quando eu tento com o código abaixo há um espaçamento do cabeçalho com o topo:
Código:

```css
header{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Web Calculator</h1>
</header>
```

Resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
}
header{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Web Calculator</h1>
</header>
```

Tente o que eu fiz.
Alguns elementos veem com formatação padrão. Como o h1 que tem que tem essa margem responsável pelos espaços que te atrapalham.

o * é um [seletor](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Getting_Started/Seletores) universal. Ou seja, estou dizendo com o:

```
*{
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Que a margin de todos os elementos deve ser zero.

Caso altere em algum a margem de algum elemento essa regra generica sera subcrita e o elemento que definir pssará a ter a margin que você determinar.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada. Se resolveu seu problema por favor marque a resposta pra que a questão fique como resolvida.

Answer (score 0):

Quando um elemento com margem (no seu caso, o `h1`) está dentro de um elemento sem `border` ou `padding`, a margem é aplicada fora do elemento pai. É o que está acontecendo com você.

O `h1` possui uma margem padrão pra cima e pra baixo, e como ele está sozinho dentro do `header`, as suas margens, tanto a de cima como a de baixo, será aplicada pra fora do `header` (elemento-pai). Isso se chama [margin collapsing](https://www.sitepoint.com/collapsing-margins/).

Você pode resolver isso simplesmente aplicando um `padding: .1px 0` no `header`:

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}
header{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: .1px 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Web Calculator</h1>
</header>
```

O CSS irá arredondar o `.1px` para `0`, mas considerará o elemento com padding e evitará que a margem do `h1` "salte" pra fora do `header`.